# Route from attribute routing not found

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API (v >2.0) webservice with a controller that does not respond entirely to my ajax request.

this is the controller

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/object")] //working
    public string Method1(string param)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Service.GetBy(param));
    }

    [Route("api/object")] //not working
    [HttpPost]
    public void Method2(string param)
    {
        Service.Insert(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(param));
    }
}
```

my ajax request (through jquery) is

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost/api/object',
    type : 'POST',
    data : { param : JSON.stringify(/* some stuff */) }
    success : successHandler,
    error : errorHandler
});
```

The `GET` method works, but the `POST` one doesn't, and it returns code 404.

It is intersting to note that the same page in two steps calls the same page to retrieve the JSONified MyObject before I submit my POST request, and that works as expected

I have configured CORS both in the webservice Web.Config and in the ajax call, how can I make it work correctly?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what status code do you get back from the request? Also, Why bother sending a serialised JSON string? Just send the request with standard parameters and let the model binder work for you.

Comment: edited with the return code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by your code examples you are working with json, with that in mind change your ajax call to this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://localhost/api/object',
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(/* my object */)
    success : successHandler,
    error : errorHandler
});
```

The `contentType` tells the web endpoint that you are sending up a http message whose content in the body of the message is *json*. You don't need to wrap your message data in an object since you're sending up a *json* string that will be your javascript object that resembles your `MyObject` class stringyfied.

Then change your controller action to this:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/object")] //working
    public string Method1(string param)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Service.GetBy(param));
    }

    [Route("api/object")] //this will work
    [HttpPost]
    public void Method2([FromBody]MyObject param)
    {
        Service.Insert(param);
    }
}
```

WebApi knows how to deal with *json* and will deserialize the message body content into your model type for you.

Comment: @fra9001 No problem buddy, glad I could help : )